# while loop conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a total noob in php and also when it comes to if while loop condition . Please be patient. First of all, I have two tables. I plan to display specific rows from right table only(the child table), but instead it displays all rows from left(parent) and right table(child) in a strange way , because if I echoed the result in sessions, it will only display first row from right table. But after I made some slight modifications, I'm able to get results but instead I get all results from both left and right table. I apologise firstly if my question above sounds silly or out of topic.I just can't think of a proper question.  Any help would be very appreciated. tq.

Here are the extract scripts below;

//calling for record from table-users and table-useradvert, joined

```
$query = "SELECT u.*, ua.* FROM users u INNER JOIN useradvert ua ON u.users.id = ua.useradvert.id";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result(); 
$row2 = $res->fetch_array();



$_SESSION['name2'] = $row2['name2'];
$_SESSION['color2'] = $row2['color2'];
$_SESSION['hobby2'] = $row2['hobby2'];
$_SESSION['radiobtn'] = $row2['radiobtn'];
$_SESSION['kupon'] = $row2['kupon'];
$_SESSION['image'] = $row2['image'];
$_SESSION['image2'] = $row2['image2'];
```

continue below extract;

```
      $output = array();
while($row2 = $res->fetch_array()) {
$output[] = $row2;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why some people downvote my question? when certain situation or problems are all not the same and requires specific and different treatment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql:

```
SELECT u.*, ua.* FROM users u INNER JOIN useradvert ua ON u.id = ua.id
```

Suggestion on php part

You need to output them in a loop or store them in a different manner in `$_SESSION` array, otherwise you will overwrite them by setting them over and over into `$_SESSION` array.

**EDIT**

```
$output = [];
while($row = $res->fetch_array()) {
  $output[] = $row;
}
```

And then formatting output in the right place

Comment: tqs @Sergey Shcherbin. do u have any idea how to loop or store them in a diff manner? I appreciate ur help.

Comment: @ml2 please check updated answer and if you find it useful upvote.

Comment: Hi.@Sergey Shcherbin. Pls be patient. I got syntax error on  $output = [];

Comment: @ml2 what version of php are you using? you can try ``$output = array()``. And what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: pls correct me if im wrong.. should it suppose to be from  u.usersid =  to  u.users.id =   (a full stop after users)

Comment: php ver 5 above. it only says syntax errors online 149. thats all when tried to save the page. ill try $output = array()

Comment: @ml2 yes sorry made mistake in sql please check updated answer. you can run in console ``php -l {{file wich gives you error}}`` to check what is actual syntax error.

Comment: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\useracc-test.php on line 44 (this is line 44:$stmt->execute();)

Comment: @ml2 it means that ``$conn->prepare($query)`` failed

Comment: ?? sorry if my question sounds silly...I assume it has something to do with either the connection to DB (which I think there is nothing wrong) or maybe the sql table query in phpmyadmin is wrong?? am I right??please correct me

Comment: @ml2 try to run SQL in phpmyadmin and check if it executes correctly

Comment: if the problem lies on the sql table. im in deep trouble. as it requires a major overhaul across all pages and the entire sql table.

Comment: @ml2 you did it wrongly tho ``$output = $row;`` should be ``$output[] = $row``

Comment: :-(  #1054 - Unknown column 'u.users.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: I already changed to $output[] = $row..but still same error..does this mean. it is because im using id(index) in useradvert table (child table) where instead I should create a seperate FK in useradvert. I referred to microsoft notes.. where it said id(index) can be treated as  FK somewhere a long time ago to boost performance.

Comment: oo.ok noted. wait a mmnt.

Comment: the error is gone.. I ran the sql in phpmyadmin.. it runs fine.. but there is no output displayed on the browser.

Comment: have you output **$output** variable anywhere in your code? and check that inside of the loop you are actually doing ``$output[] = $row``

Comment: please correct me again. if im wrong. should it be from $row --> $row2 ??

Comment: because above im using $row2

Comment: ...I feel bad dragging you to this point. Im just informing  u that, there's no error displayed. sql runs fine in phpmyadmin, but the problem is no data displayed at all. btw I appreciate ur help. and will accept your answer. tq so much...

Comment: @ml2 yes you need to use row2 instead of row from my example. Np. happy coding :) and edit your while body to also use row2 instead of row :)